# Horror story where vietnam veterans are pursued by ghosts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, ghost, military-sf

Looking for a ghost/horror story involving group of Vietnam vets pursued by ghosts from a Vietnamese cemetery. Locale is west coast USA, I believe.

Comment: What kind of story? Novel, short story, comic, movie? And can you give any indication of when it was written? And what are those horses doing in the title?

Answer (score 3):

There's a David Drake short along those lines, but it's about soldiers disturbing a site in-country during the war.

It's in *Nights and Demons*

Comment: Another one has a guy returning from Vietnam to visit the family of a guy he served with who had died in Vietnam.  Turns out the guy who "died" was a vampire who got fragged by his buddies because he kept killing them for food.  The guy visiting the family was dying of cancer or something and decided to take the rest of the vampires with him - he used a white phosphorus grenade to kill the vampires, and died with them  The willie pete was also how they'd fragged the one in 'Nam.  I think it was in "The Military Dimension."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you add a bit more of a description of the story just for future viewers?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's a short story, there is Robert McCammon's great story "Night Crawlers" that was also a episode of the New Twilight Zone.

Though I have a feeling you are either speaking of a Lucius Shepard or a Jack Cady story(both have done great Vietnam Horror/Ghost stories)

The Cady is called By Reason of Darkness and is in a Douglas E. Winter anthology called Prime Evil.

The Shepard could be"Graves" or "R n R".

All the stories are top of the line.

Comment: Can you give any info why you think it may be these one of these stories? For instance, do any of them take place on the west coast and/or have a Vietnamese cemetery in them?